# How to define a output name for flutter build ipa?

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ipa

I could not find a parameter to define the output filename of the ipa file. Is there an easy way to set the ouput filename?

I use an azure pipeline to build my ipa file:

```
- script: flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=ios/exportOptions.plist --build-number=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  displayName: Build iOS adHoc
```

I want to generate 2 ipa files. One for the AppStore with an AppStore profile and one with adHoc Profile. For that i want a second command but i cant find an easy way to declare a filename so i can have both files generated.

Comment: You could install the extension: [Flutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter) for Azure DevOps, and then use Flutter Build task to build your ipa file. As for the target command, you could submit it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues to check if there are such commands existed.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this as well. There is a note about it here.
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

> Note: When you export your app at the end of Distribute App, Xcode
> will create a directory containing an IPA of your app and an
> ExportOptions.plist file. You can create new IPAs with the same
> options without launching Xcode by running flutter build ipa
> --export-options-plist=path/to/ExportOptions.plist. See xcodebuild -h for details about the keys in this property list.